# Writing a two variable function $f(x,t)$ in terms of Dirac-Delta $\delta(x)$ function and a function $P(t)$?

Tags: functions, physics, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

How to write a two variable function $f(x,t)$  in terms of Dirac-Delta $\delta(x)$ function and a function $P(t)$?

**For example;**

I read something in a book. You can find the following picture.

But I don' t understand the logic behind this. Could you explain it?

[image]

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/487993/2451

Answer (score 0):

They want a force density but don't have a smooth load. Instead they have a point load. To represent a point load as a force density one can use Dirac $\delta$. A point load $P$ at $x=g$ is represented as the force density $f(x) = P \, \delta(x-g).$

In the example they also have that both the force $P$ and the placement $g$ varies with time $t$. This makes also the force density $f$ depend on $t$. Thus we get
$$f(x,t) = P(t) \, \delta(x-g(t)).$$